# Change the size of uitextview's text dynamically

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitextfield, uifont, uitextfielddelegate

I am trying to change the font size of a UITextView field's text by clicking on '+' and '-' buttons. I am unable to access the font size of the textfield. Please help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITextView *textView = ...;
textView.font = [textView.font fontWithSize:newSize]
```

Comment: it worked for me @Chris Wagner :D
Thanks man....but how ever it doesn't increase my textfield's height, when the text expands..!

Comment: You might want to try sizeToFit, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/sizeToFit